# Flex: Modifying Text Area

Tags: apache-flex, textarea

I'm making a text editor using Text Area. Which user can change font size, family and etc.
This is my code on as:

```
    private function ChangeFont(event: Event):void
       {
        var mySelectedTextRange:TextRange = new TextRange(thistxtarea,true,
                                                thistxtarea.selectionBeginIndex,
                                                thistxtarea.selectionEndIndex);
        mySelectedTextRange.fontSize = int(cmbbxFntSze.text);
        thistxtarea.setFocus();
       }
```

i have this combo box to enter desired font size:

```
<mx:ComboBox x="78" y="8" width="114" id="cmbbxFntFam"  close="ChangeFont(event)"></mx:ComboBox>
```

How do I change font properties if the text inside is not highlight? For example I position the mouse pointer on last index of text inside my Text Area and I select on my combo box the desired font size. The following font size of letter that inputed in Text Area should be the selected font size on combo box. The code that I post works only if I highlight the desired text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to set the style

```
private function setTextStyles(type:String, value:Object = null):void
        {
            if(thisindex != -1)
            {
                var tf:TextFormat;

                var beginIndex:int = textArea.getTextField().selectionBeginIndex;
                var endIndex:int = textArea.getTextField().selectionEndIndex;

                textArea.getTextField().alwaysShowSelection = true;

                if (beginIndex == endIndex)
                {
                    tf = previousTextFormat;
                }
                else    
                    tf = new TextFormat();


                if (type == "bold" || type == "italic" || type == "underline")
                {
                    tf[type] = value;
                }
                else if (type == "align")
                {
                    if (beginIndex == endIndex)
                    {
                        tf = new TextFormat();
                    }

                    // Apply the paragraph styles to the whole paragraph instead of just 
                    // the selected text
                    beginIndex = textArea.getTextField().getFirstCharInParagraph(beginIndex) - 1;
                    beginIndex = Math.max(0, beginIndex);
                    endIndex = textArea.getTextField().getFirstCharInParagraph(endIndex) +
                        textArea.getTextField().getParagraphLength(endIndex) - 1;
                    tf[type] = value;
                    previousTextFormat[type] = value;
                    if (!endIndex)
                        textArea.getTextField().defaultTextFormat = tf;
                }
                else if (type == "font")
                {
                    tf[type] = cmbbxFntFam.text;
                }
                else if (type == "size")
                {
                    var fontSize:uint = uint(cmbbxFntSze.text);
                    if (fontSize > 0)
                        tf[type] = fontSize;
                }
                else if (type == "color")
                {
                    tf[type] = uint(clrpckerFontColor.selectedColor);
                }


                textFormatChanged = true;

                if (beginIndex == endIndex)
                {                       
                    previousTextFormat = tf;
                }
                else
                {
                    textArea.getTextField().setTextFormat(tf,beginIndex,endIndex);//textArea.setTextFormat(tf,beginIndex,endIndex);
                }

                dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));

                var caretIndex:int = textArea.getTextField().caretIndex;
                var lineIndex:int = textArea.getTextField().getLineIndexOfChar(caretIndex);

                textArea.invalidateDisplayList();
                textArea.validateDisplayList();
                textArea.validateNow();

                // Scroll to make the line containing the caret under viewable area
                while (lineIndex >= textArea.getTextField().bottomScrollV)
                {
                    textArea.verticalScrollPosition++;
                }

                callLater(textArea.setFocus);

            }
        }
```

This code is use for getting the style from the textArea

```
 private function getTextStyles():void
        {               

            if (!textArea)
                return;

            var tf:TextFormat;

            var beginIndex:int = textArea.getTextField().selectionBeginIndex;
            var endIndex:int = textArea.getTextField().selectionEndIndex;

            if (textFormatChanged)
                previousTextFormat = null;

            if (beginIndex == endIndex)
            {
                tf = textArea.getTextField().defaultTextFormat;
                if (tf.url != "")
                {
                    var carIndex:int = textArea.getTextField().caretIndex;
                    if (carIndex < textArea.getTextField().length)
                    {
                        var tfNext:TextFormat=textArea.getTextField().getTextFormat(carIndex, carIndex + 1);

                        if (!tfNext.url || tfNext.url == "")
                            tf.url = tf.target = "";
                    }
                    else
                        tf.url = tf.target = ""; 
                }
            }
            else
                tf = textArea.getTextField().getTextFormat(beginIndex,endIndex);                


            if (cmbbxFntSze.text != tf.font)
                setComboSelection(cmbbxFntFam, tf.font);
            if (int(cmbbxFntSze.text) != tf.size)
                setComboSelection(cmbbxFntSze,String(tf.size));
            if (clrpckerFontColor.selectedColor != tf.color)
                clrpckerFontColor.selectedColor = Number(tf.color);

            if (btnBold.selected != tf.bold)
                btnBold.selected = tf.bold;//Alert.show("bold");
            if (btnItalic.selected != tf.italic)
                btnItalic.selected = tf.italic;
            if (btnUnderline.selected != tf.underline)
                btnUnderline.selected = tf.underline;


            if (tf.align == "left")
                alignButtons.selectedIndex = 0;
            else if (tf.align == "center")
                alignButtons.selectedIndex = 1;
            else if (tf.align == "right")
                alignButtons.selectedIndex = 2;
            else if (tf.align == "justify")
                alignButtons.selectedIndex = 3;



            if (textArea.getTextField().defaultTextFormat != tf)
                textArea.getTextField().defaultTextFormat = tf;
            previousTextFormat = tf;
            textFormatChanged = false;

            lastCaretIndex = textArea.getTextField().caretIndex;                
            thishtmltxt = textArea.htmlText;
            textArea.validateNow();
        }
```

Please check for minor errors, coz when i code this i have some commented traces

Answer (score 0):

Have you perhaps taken a look at how **mx.controls.RichTextEditor** does this? 
You can find it in ...**\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls**

If you scan that code you will see that the RichTextEditor retains the current text style settings in TextFormat variable it maintains, and then applies that style to newly entered text. That variable is updated when the user changes fonts/sizes or when the selection changes to grab the neighboring style. There is special consideration for the case of selectionBeginIndex == selectionEndIndex as well.

Comment: hello. I review what you suggested but there are some code their that I don't understand like this textArea.getTextField().setTextFormat textArea has no properties getTextField.Where it come from? Please help me how to figure it out.thank you

Comment: getTextField() is in the mx_internal namespace.  You'll need to import that namespace into your class, and either open it, or explicitly prefix getTextField() (i.e., mx_internal::getTextField())

Comment: hello. Anyone implemented this on runtime creation of TextArea?Please give me example on how to do it?I have a hard time tracing in override function.thank u